# pthread_barrier not behaving how I'd expect

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am running this in C++, however I think the same code would work in C. My understanding of a barrier is that when you pthread_barrier_init() you give it a number. That number represents how many threads must make a call to pthread_barrier_wait() before any of them get unblocked. So basically if the number is 4 and you have 3 threads who have executed that wait() line so far, all 3 of those threads will be blocked until a 4th thread comes along and calls pthread_barrier_wait().

I am trying to get all of the threads to begin execution at the same time.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread_func(void* args) {
    pthread_barrier_t *barrier = (pthread_barrier_t*)args;
    printf("waiting for barrier\n");
    pthread_barrier_wait(barrier);
    printf("passed barrier\n");

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int const num_threads = 4;
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    pthread_barrier_t *barrier;

    pthread_barrier_init(barrier, NULL, num_threads);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_func, (void*)barrier);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output I receive:

```
waiting for barrier
waiting for barrier
waiting for barrier
passed barrier
passed barrier
passed barrier
waiting for barrier
passed barrier
```

output I expect:

```
waiting for barrier
waiting for barrier
waiting for barrier
waiting for barrier
passed barrier
passed barrier
passed barrier
passed barrier
```

Another very strange thing occurring is that in my pthread_barrier_init(barrier, NULL, num_threads) call, I can change the number to (num_threads+40) and the program still runs. I would think that in that case, all of the threads would be sitting at their wait() calls forever in that case since there would never be num_threads+40 threads waiting.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pthread_barrier_t *barrier;
pthread_barrier_init(barrier, NULL, num_threads);
```

So `barrier` is a pointer that's never made to point to anything in particular. You never assign `barrier` a value, yet you pass its value to `pthread_barrier_init`. So `pthread_barrier_init` gets a garbage value, as do your threads.

Somewhere, you need to create an actual barrier, not just a pointer to one.

You could do this:

```
pthread_barrier_t actual_barrier;
pthread_barrier_t *barrier = &actual_barrier;
pthread_barrier_init(barrier, NULL, num_threads);
```

This actually does create a barrier and passes its address to `pthread_barrier_init` so the barrier you actually created can be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The answer @DavidSchwartz gave adds an extra line to make it clear how the pointer form would need to point to an actual instance of a `pthread_barrier_t`.  However more typical for very localized usage would be:

```
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, num_threads);
```